# Controlling GPS ON/OFF from the app

Tags: android, ios, gps, coronasdk

I am seeking for some advice from the Corona experts. I would like to control GPS ON/OFF from my app but I am not quite sure that can be achieved by using Corona.

I have couple of queries about the process-

After installing the app and then open, the app will prompt for enabling GPS (if that turned OFF on that device and sharing location permission is already given), am I right?

If the sharing location permission denied by the user then can the app will be able to ask for permission again and prompt for enabling the GPS?

If I turn ON the GPS from my app settings and then again turn OFF, then it is possible to show popup notification message to turn on the GPS?

Someone said that it only display the permission notification prompt message once and after that no way to show the prompt message to control the location service.

Looking forward to get some expert advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The system will only display the permission dialog once. You can check the permission yourself and display your own alert if permission is denied. I don't know how todo this in Corona

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do any of these with Corona SDK. You will need Enterprise version to play with permissions and settings. Even then you have to code in Java not Corona.